# Need help for some white space to be removed from the right side of the site..!

Tags: html, css, whitespace, resolution, removing-whitespace

I have been going through this whole site..almost..complete everything..Just one things seems to be missing..which is that right on the homepage the slider has some space on the right side..
Here is live link please to the site : http://universal.huntedhunter.com/

Here is the slider code :

```
<div style="position: absolute; left:-5px;">
<ul class="bxslider">
<li><img alt="" src="http://www.webngraphicssolutions.com/universal/wp-content/themes/universal/content/sec-01-bg.jpg" /></li>
<li><img alt="" src="http://www.webngraphicssolutions.com/universal/wp-content/themes/universal/wall/1.JPG" /></li>
<li><img alt="" src="http://www.webngraphicssolutions.com/universal/wp-content/themes/universal/wall/2.JPG" /></li>
<li><img alt="" src="http://www.webngraphicssolutions.com/universal/wp-content/themes/universal/wall/3.JPG" /></li>
</ul>
<img alt="" src="http://www.webngraphicssolutions.com/universal/wp-content/themes/universal/content/sec-01-bottom.png" style="position:absolute; top:92.5%; left:0.75%;" />
</div>
```

It seems nothing to change here...Almost..also the slider images has natural 1366x768 pixels resolution...but it shows 1356x762 resolution images at slider when someone open site...

Here is CSS file for Slider : http://www.pastebin.com/3xZWXhsU

it seems so strange..
So please..need your help..!

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do with that gap ?

Comment: I'm on a 1680x1050 resolution at work and I see a 300PX gap.  Your images are not scaling to fill the width of the slider, you have a larger problem than just 10 pixels missing.

Comment: Yeah..that's what....seems strange..so how is it gonna to be fixed..please..! I want to remove that gap..!

Comment: You need to make sure that your images get a 100% width.

Comment: Well,almost images..has width :100%; in CSS...

Comment: I suggest you to protect the main domain with a .htaccess or a blanck index.php to avoid the file listing/download

Comment: @Asenar: Yeah...thanks..for your suggestion..! Will do that..!

Comment: Here is CSS file for Slider : http://pastebin.com/3xZWXhsU

Comment: Then don't sit around for people to attempt to fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, it is - because if you don't stop trying to bump the question, you make the question messy and extremely hard to follow. People will also end up not helping you for the sheer reason of you being pushy and demanding people to fix your own problem which you probably could have figured out by now if you spent the time debugging and not hustling people for an answer.

Comment: It's ok...! Anyway..thanks..!

Comment: Thanks @patricksweeney : I fixed...site...! myself..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Like "left:-5px" is added, remove that will work fine 
File : jquery.bxslider.css
Line Number : 34

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
/* left: -5px; */
background: #fff;
-webkit-transform: translatez(0);
-moz-transform: translatez(0);
-ms-transform: translatez(0);
-o-transform: translatez(0);
transform: translatez(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks..for reply..but besides...I removed that..still shows...same like that..! nothing changed..!

Comment: @user3515275 Calm down. Not everyone is sitting on the site waiting for the next comment to reply to it. Everyone has different things happening in their lives. If they are willing and able to reply and see your comment, then they will reply. Posting "bump" or other pestering comments isn't going to speed things up.

Comment: @ajp15243 : Thanks..for your advice...!